# javascript file cordova.. how to pass value through variable

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am developing intel cordova app...
to download files from server , i have included cordova file download plugin but it has data that i want to pass through variable...
here is my code:

```
var app = {

fileName: "PointerEventsCordovaPlugin.wmv", //<-- pass this value through variable (dynamic)
uriString: "http://media.ch9.ms/ch9/8c03/f4fe2512-59e5-4a07-bded-124b06ac8c03/PointerEventsCordovaPlugin.wmv",  // <-- this one also
// Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
```

....
I have added fileName and uristring.. but i want to add that value dynamically from variable.. how can i do this?????
[cordova plugin link](https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download/blob/master/test/js/index.js)
please if  you know anything about this than reply...

Answer (score 0):

Following the example from the link you provided, remove the *fileName* and *uriString* fields from the *app* object, and parameterize the needed functions. For example, startDownload will become:

```
startDownload: function (fileName, uriString) {

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function (newFile) {
            app.downloadFile(uriString, newFile);
        });
    });
},
```